# Intelligent DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, datetime, nlp

`DateTime.Parse` can already handle [a number of formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, I want to use it to read input from a user, so there are several important features I'd like to have.

- Correctly interpret as many natural language expressions like "tomorrow", "next week", "in a fortnight" as possible
- Handle misspelled ("Arpil") or badly formatted dates (when it is possible to make a good guess)
- Handle incomplete dates (eg. for "9 may" assume the nearest future 9 May - May 9th, 2016)

Does such an extended `DateTime` already exist? If not, are there any libraries or functions I can use to build my own?

I would prefer to have some distinction between no-brainer decisions and educated guesses, so that in the former case, I can prompt the user with `Did you mean May 9th, 2016? (y/n)`, and in the latter just say `Assuming you meant May 9th, 2016.` (they can go back and edit it if they want).

Comment: @alvas Does that work locally or does it connect to their server every time?

Comment: https://wit.ai/docs/console/quickstart

Comment: That is why they invented a DateTimePicker.  Use Picker!!!

Comment: _Does such an extended DateTime already exist?_ No. _Are there any libraries or functions I can use to build my own?_ Off topic question.